# Spring Boot converter ignored for nested property

Tags: spring-boot, type-conversion

I have a `TaskFilter` being used as parameter in a `@RestController` :

```java
@GetMapping("/tasks")
public ResponseEntity<List<TaskDTO>> getAllTasks(Pageable pageable, TaskFilter filter)
```

If I call `GET /api/tasks?priority=low` then it works fine, the constructor is called. But if I call with a nested property `GET /api/tasks?priority.gte=low` it fails. If the nested property is a string for exemple, no problem. But here spring boots seems to completely ignore my converter.

If the mapping (on another route) expects a `TaskPriority` at the root level it is converted without issue, but when used as a property of an object, the conversion does not happen and an exception is thrown.

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class TaskPriorityFilter extends OrderedEnumFilter<TaskPriority> {

    @JsonCreator
    public TaskPriorityFilter(String tp) {
        super(TaskPriority.forValue(tp));
    }
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
abstract public class OrderedEnumFilter<E extends OrderedEnum> extends AbstractComparableFilter<E> {

    public OrderedEnumFilter(E eq) {
        super(eq);
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        if (null != eq) return eq.getOrder();
        if (null != gte) return gte.getOrder();
        if (null != gt) return gt.getOrder();
        if (null != lte) return lte.getOrder();
        if (null != lt) return lt.getOrder();
        if (null != between) return between.stream().map(OrderedEnum::getOrder).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return null;
    }
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
abstract public class AbstractComparableFilter<T> implements PolymorphicFilter {

    static protected AtomicInteger identifierCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

    protected T eq;
    protected T gte;
    protected T gt;
    protected T lte;
    protected T lt;
    protected List<T> between;

    protected final int id;

    public void resetIfTooHigh() {
        identifierCount.compareAndSet(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1, 0);
    }

    public AbstractComparableFilter() {
        this.id = identifierCount.getAndIncrement();
        resetIfTooHigh();
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public AbstractComparableFilter(T eq) {
        this.eq = eq;
        this.id = identifierCount.getAndIncrement();
        resetIfTooHigh();
    }

    public String getStartKey() {
        return "betweenStart" + id;
    }

    public String getEndKey() {
        return "betweenEnd" + id;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        if (null != eq) return eq;
        if (null != gte) return gte;
        if (null != gt) return gt;
        if (null != lte) return lte;
        if (null != lt) return lt;
        if (null != between) return between;

        return null;
    }

    public ComparableType getFilterType() {
        if (null != eq) return ComparableType.EQ;
        if (null != gte) return ComparableType.GTE;
        if (null != gt) return ComparableType.GT;
        if (null != lte) return ComparableType.LTE;
        if (null != lt) return ComparableType.LT;
        if (null != between) return ComparableType.BETWEEN;

        throw new InvalidOperationException("unknown filter subtype");
    }
}
```

```java
public enum TaskPriority {
    High(75),
    Medium(50),
    Low(25)
    ;

    private final Integer order;

    TaskPriority(Integer order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public Integer getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static TaskPriority forValue(String value) {
        return valueOf(CaseFormat.LOWER_HYPHEN.to(CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL, value));
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static TaskPriority forValue(Integer order) {
        return Stream.of(TaskPriority.values())
            .filter(c -> order.equals(c.getOrder()))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String toValue() {
        return CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_HYPHEN, name());
    }
}
```

I've declared a custom converter, the converter is correctly registered, but is not used during the conversion process :

```java
@Configuration
public class CustomConvertersConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new StringToTaskPriorityConverter());
    }
}
```

I've also tried to add the `@Component` annotation, and it doesn't change anything :

```java
@Component
public class StringToTaskPriorityConverter implements Converter<String, TaskPriority> {
    @Override
    public TaskPriority convert(String source) {
        return null == source ? null : TaskPriority.forValue(source);
    }
}
```

EDIT : I previously wrote a simplified version, with this edit the code presented here is exactly the same as in my code.

Also, as a recap :

- `GET /api/tasks?priority=low` results in a 200
- `GET /api/tasks?priority.gte=low` results in a 400

**Both should results in a 200.**

Comment: `GET /api/tasks?priority.gte=low` works without any error. Do you mean to say `GET /api/tasks?priority.gte=25` is not working?

Comment: I mean 'priority.gte=low' is not working. While 'priority=low' is working.

Comment: That is strange. I copied your code to set up a sample project and is working (I didn't use `lombok` but I don't think that makes any difference). I will create a github repo

Comment: I have added the git repo. My suspicion is you have put the `StringToTaskPriorityConverter` in a totally different package and is not getting scanned

Comment: Yet it is being registered. When I use the debugger the breakpoint is triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Following constructor causes the `StringToTaskPriorityConverter` being ignored. (Initially the question had `TaskPriority` as constructor param, it is the reason my repo had the opposite behaviour to your question)

```
    @JsonCreator
    public TaskPriorityFilter(String tp) {
       super(TaskPriority.forValue(tp));
    }
```

- Replace the constructor with

```
    @JsonCreator
    public TaskPriorityFilter(TaskPriority tp) {
       super(tp);
    }
```

- Added one more custom converter as follows.

```
   @Component
public class StringToTaskPriorityFilterConverter implements 
                            Converter<String, TaskPriorityFilter> {
   @Override
   public TaskPriorityFilter convert(String source) {

       System.out.println("StringToTaskPriorityFilterConverter 
                                        is called for " + source);
       if (source == null)
           return null;
       try {
           return new 
TaskPriorityFilter(TaskPriority.forValue(Integer.parseInt(source)));
       } catch (Exception e) {
           return new TaskPriorityFilter(TaskPriority.forValue(source));
       }
   }
}
```

- With the above changes `?priority=low` and `?priority.gte=low` are both working.
- However I am not sure about the reason the Constructor with string param causes the custom converter to be ignored.

**Reference**

Github repo that allows following 3 requests. https://github.com/kavi-kanap/stackoverflow-62970847

- [GET /tasks?priority.gte=low](http://localhost:8080/tasks?priority.gte=low)
- [GET tasks?priority.gte=25](http://localhost:8080/tasks?priority.gte=25)
- [GET tasks?priority=low](http://localhost:8080/tasks?priority=low)

Comment: I tried your repo, priority.gte=low works, but priority=low doesn't.

Comment: So is it opposite to what you see in your code? because I didn't check `priority=low` as it wasn't mentioned as issue in your question

Comment: Do you mind updating the question with list of endpoints that works and endpoints that you expect to work but doesn't work as bullet points?

Comment: I just had a baby, I'll get back to you before the bounty expires.

Comment: Don't worry about the bounty and first enjoy the time with your baby

Comment: Ok so... my issue was in my IT I didn't add the custom converters, for some reason the annotated `@Component` were not caught up. Also the string constructor `public TaskPriorityFilter(String tp)` makes the filter custom converter unecessary.