# How to send json with GET params via Spring Boot / Tomcat?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, parameters, get

so currently I'm working on a project where we have product objects which in turn contain "Origin" objects (containing `region: String` and `country: String`).

What I'm trying to do is a RestController which takes in an **optional** Origin object and does something with it (e.g. logs it).

This is what I have right now:

```
@GetMapping("search")
    public Page<Wine> getProductByStuff(
            @RequestParam(required = false) Origin origin, 
            /* other attributes */) {
    log.info(origin); // it has a proper toString method.
}
```

There are two problem with this approach. First of all, when I send a request like:

`http://[...]/search?origin={"region":"blah","country":"UK"}`

or even the html converted string like:

`http://[...]/search?origin={%22region%22:%22blah%22%44%22country%22:%22UK%22}`

... it says

> Invalid character found in the request target [/api/products/search?origin={%22region%22:%22blah%22%44%22country%22:%22DE%22}]. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986.

Afaik the only valid characters Tomcat has that I need are {}. All others I've replaced with the html encoded chars and it still doesn't work.

What I did to prevent this:

```
@Component
public class TomcatWebServerCustomizer
        implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        TomcatConnectorCustomizer a = null;
        factory.addConnectorCustomizers(connector -> {
            connector.setAttribute("relaxedPathChars", "<>[\\]^`{|},\"");
            connector.setAttribute("relaxedQueryChars", "<>[\\]^`{|},\"");
        });
    }
}
```

(See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51703746/setting-relaxedquerychars-for-embedded-tomcat), which is, by the way, deprecated (at least connector.setAttribute).)

This produced:

> MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type '[censored].backend.model.Origin'.

My questions are:

- (How) is it possible to configure Tomcat/Spring so that they can actually accept json in the url params?
- How would I format it in e.g. Postman so that it would work? Currently I'm just converting special characters by hand in the params tab of Postman.

Comment: Why are you trying to send JSON object with GET as URL parameters? To send in the URL it should be key/value pairs. Do you have any special purpose? You can just send it with a POST request in the body.

Comment: Well, I'm using a GET request since it fits the situation the most (it's a search query after all) and I'm not simply writing the attributes of origin into the path cause it makes it harder in the front end since I can't just put product.origin in there but have to deconstruct it. If it's not possible, Imma do that though.

Comment: @TahaYavuzBodur I highly disagree wrt. the POST part of your comment. A POST should change the server state, i.e. if data is only fetched, it should be a GET. But I agree wrt. the JSON-part. Request-parameters are meant as key-value pairs, not complex objects.

Comment: Discussion on using GET vs POST when using body: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body.  There is not really any consensus, but the latest HTTP spec doesn't mention anything to the contrary, so I would recommend doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Here is what you need to do if you want to send it as json query param.

```
     @RestController
     public class OriginController {

      @GetMapping("/search")
      public void getOrigin(@RequestParam(value = "origin", required = false) 
                            Origin origin) {
        System.out.println(origin);
      }

     }
```

- Register a converter

```
    @Component
   public class StringToOriginConverter implements 
                              Converter<String, Origin> {

      ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

      @Override
      public Origin convert(String source) {
         try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(source, Origin.class);
         } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            //You could throw some exception here instead for custom error
            return null;
         }

       }
    }
```

- Sending from `postman`
  [image]

**Note**

My answer is not debating whether you should use `POST` or `GET` as it is not what you have asked. It is just providing one option if you want to send some payload as query param

Comment: OMG that actually works (after I figured out "Converter" is from Spring, not from Jackson)! Thank you so, so much. I had no idea something like this exist! Do you mind sharing where you know this from?

Comment: I have using for long and recently as couple of days ago on this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62970847/spring-boot-converter-ignored-for-nested-property?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#core-convert

Comment: Hey, just a little question in a smiliar question. I have another method accepting Collection<String> idList but if I send idList=1,2 it works and if I send idList=[1,2] (encoded via Postman like you showed me) it interprets that as [[1,2]] and fails number conversion. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, don't use JSON as a path parameter.

Directly use path parameters, and convert to `Origin` object.

```
@GetMapping("search")
public Page<Wine> getProductByStuff(
        @RequestParam(required = false) String region,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String country, /* other attributes */) {
    Origin origin = new Origin(region, country);
    log.info(origin); // it has a proper toString method.
}
```